# Replace a Raid 0 Disk (Software Raid/Windows)

Tags: windows, software-raid, raid-0

I would like to know if it is possible, to replace a Disk in a Windows Software Raid 0. (e.g. clone the disk to another one inside the OS)

I have seen another post where this question was asked, but it was written regarding to a Hardware Raid.